# During model.fit() 'NoneType' object is not callable, ambiguous truth series

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I am trying to train a model for sentiment analysis,

I am getting the following error:

```
Training model with https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-4_H-512_A-8/1
Epoch 1/5
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-118-21a4b57536e8> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 print(f'Training model with {tfhub_handle_encoder}')
----> 2 history = classifier_model.fit(x=train_data['clean_text'], y=train_data['sentiment'],
      3                                validation_data=val_data.empty,
      4                                epochs=epochs)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/polymorphic_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    855       # In this case we have created variables on the first call, so we run the
    856       # defunned version which is guaranteed to never create variables.
--> 857       return self._no_variable_creation_fn(*args, **kwds)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
    858     elif self._variable_creation_fn is not None:
    859       # Release the lock early so that multiple threads can perform the call

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

When calling the following function:

```
print(f'Training model with {tfhub_handle_encoder}')
history = classifier_model.fit(x=train_data['clean_text'], y=train_data['sentiment'],
                               validation_data=val_data.empty,
                               epochs=epochs)
```

The shape of my train_data is (534, 2) and the validation data is (35,2)

A sample of the train_data looks like the below:

| clean_text | sentiment |
| --- | --- |
| really enjoyed the movie | 2.0 |

Has anyone any idea what is going wrong? Can't seem to make much sense of the error. Oddly I also need the .empty on the val_data or I get

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I believe my inputs are incorrect but I'm not sure why as when I print the shape the model expects I get the following:

```
(None,) <dtype: 'string'>
(None, 1) <dtype: 'float32'>
text [(None,)] string
preprocessing None float32
BERT_encoder {'input_mask': (None, 128), 'input_word_ids': (None, 128), 'input_type_ids': (None, 128)} float32
dropout_4 (None, 512) float32
classifier (None, 512) float32
[None, None, None, None, None]
```

Answer (score 1):

`validation_data`   parameter requires input type of

- `A tuple (x_val, y_val)` of `Numpy` arrays or `tensors`.
- `A tuple` (x_val, y_val, val_sample_weights) of `NumPy` arrays.
- A tf.data.Dataset. - A Python generator or `keras.utils.Sequence` returning `(inputs, targets)` or `(inputs, targets, sample_weights)`.

`validation_data=(input,target)`

- `input` is your `clean_text`
- `target` is `sentiment`